# What should I use for this?

Tags: python, syntax

OK. I'm back on track for my quest to make a server-sided laughing man head for my Toontown private server. Now, I've made an if statement to filter who IS ME and who ISN'T ME.

```
    if invoker.getName() = "Toonman"
```

But, It said invalid syntax. I came here to ask, what is the proper syntax for this line of python code?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: So someone flagged my question for no reason at all?

Comment: Use double equals. Single equals is for assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if invoker.getName() == "Toonman":
```

Answer (score 2):

`=` is an assignment

`==` is an equality check.

`is` is an identity check (thanks!)

Comment: `is` is an *identity* check, not an equality check. If you do `a = []; b = []` you have `a == b` but you *don't* have `a is b`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if invoker.getName() = "Toonman"
```

In the code above, `if invoker.getName()`is correct, as is `"Toonman"`. The error comes because in a statement like this, `if` requires a `==` operator.

From http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_basic_operators.htm:

`=` "Assigns values from right side operands to left side operand"

`==` If the values of two operands are equal, then the condition becomes true.

Basically you use `=` when you are setting something like `name = "Toonman"`, and use `==` when you are checking something like `if name == "Toonman":`.

Comment: Thank you. I already had an awnser, and then with lua on roblox i learnt the actual meaning. heres a lua example. `for i,v in pairs(game.Players:children()) do if v.Name == "hello" then v:Kick() end`. Once again, thank you for your in-detail response!